# Footer is overlaping wrapper and post on my HTML page

Tags: html, css

I'm making an assignment that I can only use HTML/CSS to make a website. I'm having a problem with my website footer on my posts page. The footer goes from the beginning of a wrapper that I have and overlaps the other post and doesn't fit the body as well. I'll send two links, one of the posts page and other with the CSS classes and id's that I'm using! Hope I can get some help!

Here is the link with the page + the CSS that I'm using on it:

https://codepen.io/brumone/pen/wjgJBx`Link`

PS: I've put the whole CSS on it, so it doesn't look weird.

Comment: Make footer element position relative or static

Comment: There is  so many possibility of improvement of your code. I am happy help you just comment me on answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues 
- The `div` tag for the wrapper was not closing 
- The position for `footer`  css is changed from `absolute` to `static`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.home{
    background-image: url("../imgs/imgburgerbg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.form-group{
  padding: 10px;
}
.msg-erro{
  color: red;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
}

header{
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(204, 36, 47);
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

 .navbar ul {
   list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(204, 36, 47);
    text-align: center;
 }

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
 }

.navbar li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 }

.navbar li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
  text-align: center;
 }

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
  }

#content{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
               0px 8px 13px rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.1),
               0px 18px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: white;
}

hr{
  width: 400px;
  border-top: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

footer {
  position: static;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(204, 36, 47);
  }

input[type=text], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: vertical;
}

label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=email] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 19px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.form-container{
  border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}

.col-25 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.col-75{
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.wrapFooter{
  position: static;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(204, 36, 47);
  font-size: small;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.post {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.imgburger{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Reviews</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <h1>burgeReview</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="navbar">
        <nav>
          <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
                <li><a href="post.html">Reviews</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="conteudo">
          <div class="post">
              <h2>Titulo</h2>
              <h5>28 de abril, 2018</h5>
              <img src="assets/imgs/burger1.jpeg" class="imgburger" alt="">
              <p>Great burger, really salty and</p>
          </div>
          <div class="post">
              <h2>Titulo</h2>
              <p>Great burger, really salty and</p>
          </div>
          <div class="post">
              <h2>Titulo</h2>
              <p>Great burger, really salty and</p>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
        <footer>
          <h2>Copyright &copy; Daniel Brum</h2>
        </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why make position absolute to static. It's by default static

Comment: We can rely on the defaults. However since the original code had defined it as `absolute` I have included `static` in the answer to make it explicit

Comment: Ok @mohit mutha. No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to major improvement in your code but here the link of [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjNZBr#anon-login)
Hopefully that help you. Below are footer CSS

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(204, 36, 47);
  }
```